# How to get typescript autocomplete to work with function parameter as untyped record?

Tags: typescript

I am working through a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) and got most of the way there, except it is not autocompleting/typing the `options` correctly:

```
type Definition = {
  code: number
  note: (opts: Record<string, unknown>) => string
}

const errors: Record<string, Definition> = {
  invalid_form: {
    code: 3,
    note: ({ name }) => `Form '${name}' is not valid`,
  },
  invalid_type: {
    code: 2,
    note: ({ name, type }) => `Value '${name}' is not '${type}' type`,
  },
  missing_property: {
    code: 1,
    note: ({ name }) => `Property '${name}' missing`,
  },
}

type Errors = typeof errors
type Name = keyof Errors

function findError<N extends Name>(name: N, options: Parameters<Errors[Name]['note']>[0]) {
  const handler = errors[name]
  const text = handler.note(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_type', { foo: 'string' })
```

Notice the `foo: 'string'` at the bottom, it should be erroring, and when I type `n` in the key, it should autocomplete `name` since that is the defined property for `invalid_type` (even though name property is an unknown type). It should also autocomplete `invalid_type` as I type the string (which it is currently not, I'm guessing because of the `Record<string, Definition>` type?).

How can I accomplish this in TypeScript? I would like to avoid having to create a "type" for each `note` function options, that would be overkill since it is just a map of string keys to any stringable value. Because having to write a type for each `note` function (of which there could be dozens / a hundred) would be overkill IMO, so hoping to avoid that if possible.

I feel like somehow the `options: Parameter...` type must involve `extends` and a conditional inferred type to get at the keys of the parameters, and build a type from that somehow, but I'm having trouble figuring out how that might work. I tried this, but it didn't change anything:

```
function findError<
  N extends Name,
  O extends Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0],
>(
  name: N,
  options: {
    [P in keyof O]: O[P]
  },
) {
  const handler = errors[name]
  const text = handler?.note(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_type', { foo: 'array' })
```

Or this:

```
function findError<N extends Name>(
  name: N,
  options: Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0] extends infer O
    ? {
        [P in keyof O]: O[P]
      }
    : never,
) {
  const handler = errors[name]
  const text = handler?.note(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_type', { foo: 'array' })
```

Or even:

```
function findError<N extends Name>(
  name: N,
  options: Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0] extends infer O
    ? {
        [KeyType in keyof O as {} extends Record<KeyType, unknown>
          ? never
          : KeyType]: O[KeyType]
      }
    : never,
) {
  const handler = errors[name]
  const text = handler?.note(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_type', { foo: 'array' })
```

Note: I put the `Record<string, Definition>` on the errors map so you get type hinting there too, when creating the definitions.

#### Update

I got the autocomplete to work:

```
function findError<N extends Name>(
  name: N,
  options: Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0],
) {
  const handler = errors[name]
  const text = handler?.note(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_form', { name: 'any', type: 'asdf' })
```

But the `handler?.note(options)` is now giving me:

```
Argument of type '{ name: any; } | { name: any; type: any; } | { name: any; another: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: any; } & { name: any; type: any; } & { name: any; another: any; }'.
  Type '{ name: any; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: any; } & { name: any; type: any; } & { name: any; another: any; }'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{ name: any; }' but required in type '{ name: any; type: any; }'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: You don't have `name` autocomplete because `type Definition` expects `Record<string, unknown>`. You should use type `{name: string, type?: string}` instead. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/w29kxW)

Comment: But the errors can have any number and possibly endless properties...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for this solution:

```js
function findError<N extends Name>(
  name: N,
  options: Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0],
) {
  const handler = errors[name]
  const text = handler?.note(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_form', { name: 'any', type: 'asdf' })
```

You are getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{ name: any; } | { name: any; type: any; } | { name: any; another: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: any; } & { name: any; type: any; } & { name: any; another: any; }'.
  Type '{ name: any; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: any; } & { name: any; type: any; } & { name: any; another: any; }'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{ name: any; }' but required in type '{ name: any; type: any; }'.ts(2345)
```

Because function arguments are in contravariant position, this is why TS after inference intersects them - for safety. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type#answer-50375286) answer for more explanation.

The problem is in this line `const handler = errors[name]`
`handler` has a type of a union of several function. Ask yourself - what is the safest way to call such function ? THe safest way is to provide a type which will be safe for each function or in other words intersect (merge) a type of each argument.
In order to fix it , you need to end up with intersection of all functions instead of unionizing them.

COnsider this example:

```js
type WithName = {
  name: string
}

type WithType = WithName & {
  type: string
}

type Opts = WithName | WithType

type Definition = {
  code: number
  note: (opts: Record<PropertyKey, string>) => string
}

const errors = {
  invalid_form: {
    code: 3,
    note: ({ name }: WithName) => `Form '${name}' is not valid`,
  },
  invalid_type: {
    code: 2,
    note: ({ name, type }: WithType) => `Value '${name}' is not '${type}' type`,
  },
  missing_property: {
    code: 1,
    note: ({ name }: WithName) => `Property '${name}' missing`,
  },
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Errors = typeof errors
type Name = keyof Errors

function findError<N extends Name>(
  name: N,
  options: Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0],
) {
  const handler = errors[name].note
  const overloadedHandler = handler as unknown as UnionToIntersection<typeof handler>
  const text = overloadedHandler(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_form', { name: 'any' })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBQVgw)

Now, `findError` expects exact type of argument for `invalid_form` and forbids using `type` property

Furthermore, using `Definition` for all kind of `note` functions is not the best idea because you want to know exact type of second argument when you provide first argument to `findError`. Using `Record<string,unknown>` is vogue.

In order to infer your types it worth using `satisfies` with `as const` assertion:

```js
type WithName = {
  name: string
}

type WithType = WithName & {
  type: string
}

type Opts = WithName | WithType

type Definition = {
  code: number
  note(opts: Record<string, unknown>): string
}

const errors = {
  invalid_form: {
    code: 3,
    note: ({ name }: WithName) => `Form '${name}' is not valid`,
  },
  invalid_type: {
    code: 2,
    note: ({ name, type }: WithType) => `Value '${name}' is not '${type}' type`,
  },
  missing_property: {
    code: 1,
    note: ({ name }: WithName) => `Property '${name}' missing`,
  },
} as const satisfies Record<string, Definition>

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Errors = typeof errors
type Name = keyof Errors

function findError<N extends Name>(
  name: N,
  options: Parameters<Errors[N]['note']>[0],
) {
  const handler = errors[name].note
  const overloadedHandler = handler as unknown as UnionToIntersection<typeof handler>
  const text = overloadedHandler(options)
  return new Error(text)
}

findError('invalid_form', { name: 'any' })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mblaPw)

Please take a look on `Definition` declaration:

```js
type Definition = {
  code: number
  note(opts: Record<string, unknown>): string
}
```

I made `note` as a method instead of arrow function. I wanted to loose strictness, because methods are bivariant (less safe). Try to convert it to arrow function and you will get an error near `satisfies`.

You can find more information and explanation in my [blog](https://catchts.com/react-props)

Comment: I am [getting an error](https://imgur.com/a/4OcH3o0) with the `satisfies`. I am using typescript 4.9.4, is that the right version? I guess I'll try upgrading to 5? Nope, same error.

Comment: Also, no way to avoid the `as unknown as`?

Comment: @Lance I am using 5.0.4, please share your playground instead of image. No, no way to avoid `as unknown`